# tinymce, view only

Tags: tinymce

Evaluating Tinymce. I've looked at the docs/source/api, and have a question that I thought I'd pose to the stackoverflow group.

Has anyone implemented Tinymce, who can tell me it it's possible to setup Tinymce to restrict a user, allowing the user to only "view" a text file, and be able to add additional buttons to the save/cancel row of buttons..

I think it should be, and that I'm missing something subtle..

Thanks

-Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you set the [read-only option](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/readonly). Configure your textarea like this in your javascript file:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    theme : "advanced",
    readonly : 1
});
```